# MyISAM or InnoDB to use for my Large project, to do multiple work at a time

Tags: php, mysql

As I have no more knowledge then usual about MyISAM, InnoDB engines, So I'm in confusion what engine to use for my large project, where

> 1) minimum 3000 users will log their account at a time (within hour)
>
> 2) and do some work like Update, delete data from their Account etc.

I'm on shared host. May anyone give me specific answer that what engine should I use for faster processing for above condition.

which database engine will speed up above works ? any help plz ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When it is time for a table to change from MyISAM to InnoDb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729806/when-it-is-time-for-a-table-to-change-from-myisam-to-innodb)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much faster is MyISAM compared to InnoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970420/how-much-faster-is-myisam-compared-to-innodb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your application use Foreign keys? If so, then you'll need to use the InnoDB engine. If it doesn't you can go ahead with MyISAM engine.

If there are many modifications of the data, it's said that InnoDB works faster because it uses row locking instead of table locking, like MyISAM. However, if there are mainly SELECT statements, a MyISAM table might be faster.

However, it's always important what the needs of a specific table are - so I would choose the storage engine that best fits the requirements for the given table. If you need foreign key constraints or transactions, you can only use InnoDB, wheras if you need fulltext indexes, you can only use MyISAM tables at the moment.

With replication it's even possible to take advantage of both storage engines on one table. For example, the master could store a table as InnoDB which makes it fast for INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs while the slave(s) could store the same table as MyISAM and offer the best performance for SELECTs.

[Source](http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2006/02/innodb-or-myisam-whats-your-preference.html)

Answer (score 2):

both engines have advantages and disadvantages

1. MYISAM

   - myisam is very simple to use, thus it is  easy to write third-party tools to interact with it.
   - myisam have been around for a while so it's highly optimized
   - myisam uses less memory than InnoDb and the actual data files are often quite a bit larger for Innodb
2. InnoDb

   - performance : u can read this blog about innodb's performance against myisam and falcon http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/08/innodb-vs-myisam-vs-falcon-benchmarks-part-1/
   - InnoDB is a largely ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) engine, it supports transactions
   - InnoDB can run a backup job in a single transaction and pull consistent, database-wide backups with only a short lock at the beginning of the job. on the other hand myisam consistent back up requires database locks and this is totally unacceptable for a large websites.